# Caching fetch() results when building a statically generated site (SSG) with Next.js

Tags: next.js, caching, fetch-api, vercel

I'm having a hard time figuring out why caching isn't working as it should while building a statically generated site (SSG) in Next.js.

I have around 400 pages, each triggering several requests to Notion to fetch some data. Since I use Notion's SDK, I am passing a custom `fetch()` to it in order to leverage Next.js' caching functionality:

```
const notion = new Client({
  auth: NOTION_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  notionVersion: NOTION_VERSION,
  fetch: (url, opts) => {
    return fetch(url, {
      ...opts,
      next: { tags: ['notion'] },
      cache: 'force-cache',
    })
  }
})
```

If I build the project locally, it looks as if caching works (`/.next/cache/fetch-cache/` is populated with a *lot* of responses from Notion). Furthermore, subsequent `next build`s succeed blazingly fast.

If I try and deploy this on Vercel, things seem to change: deploys are awfully slow and a few log statements show that every time requests hit Notion. If I go to the Usage -> Data Cache section, it's blank.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure Vercel's `fetch()` cache works as expected?